# Apply error css to all empty input on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to apply `border-bottom` to all input that is empty on click event using the snippet below

```
var formElements = [];
    $("form :input").each(function(){
        formElements.push($(this));
    });

    if (formElements[1][0].value == '') {
        $("#username").css('border-bottom', '2px solid red').focus();
        return false;
    }
    if (formElements[0][0].value == '') {
        $("#id").css('border-bottom', '2px solid red');
        return false;
    }
```

jQuery only apply CSS to the last element, how can I apply CSS to ALL divs without using multiple statements.

Comment: Please post your html code with question.,

Comment: Why are you going one by one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your way seems very complicated. Seems like the easiest solution is to loop over inputs, check values, and add a class.

```js
var inputs = $("form :input").removeClass("error")
inputs.filter( (i,e) => !e.value.length ).addClass("error");
//inputs.filter( function (i,e) { return !e.value.length; } ).addClass("error");
```

```css
.error {
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input value="aaa" />
  <input value="" />
  <input value="" />
  <select>
    <option value="">pick</option>
    <option value="x">test</option>
  </select>
  <select>
    <option value="">pick</option>
    <option value="x" selected>Test</option>
  </select>  
  
</form>
```

Now the reason why yours was stopping was because you have return false. It would go into an if and stop.

Comment: Thank you. If I need to prevent form submission using your code, how may can I do that?

Comment: `var errors = inputs.filter(....).addClass(...); return errors.length===0`

Answer (score 0):

Simply try this

```
var hasFocus = false; 
$( "form :input" ).each( function(){
    var $this = $( this );
    if ( $this.val().length == 0 )
    {
       $this.css( 'border-bottom', '2px solid red' );
    }
    if ( !hasFocus )
    {
       $this.focus(); 
       hasFocus = true; //set to true so that next erroneous input doesn't get focussed
    }
});
```